# Why "Could not cast value of type" error still occurring?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-controls

I'm trying to have a custom cell on the tableview but I am getting `Could not cast value of type` error. I have looked at majority of other posts, but the error still occurs. Link is picture of the error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf1ukch3ciigr4z/Screenshot%202015-10-05%2023.15.11.png?dl=0

```
var arrayOfConcerts: [ConcertsController] = [ConcertsController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.setUpConcerts()
self.table1.dataSource = self

self.table1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}    

func setUpConcerts(){
let concert1 = ConcertsController(imageName: "ACL.png")

arrayOfConcerts.append(concert1)
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return arrayOfConcerts.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellconcert", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellConcerts
let concert = arrayOfConcerts[indexPath.row]
cell!.setCell(concert.imageName)
return cell!
}
```

Comment: Did you register cell like this? `self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Comment: Yes, I did it both ways

Comment: Hey, why are you calling dequeue function on `table1`. It must be `tableView`! Any specific reason for having an IBOutlet for your table view? You could do all activities in storyboard itself.

Comment: I changed it, but I am still getting the same error. The tableview is a nib file.

Comment: The tableview is in a nib file not in the traditional storyboard.

Comment: While registering your table view for your cell can you also try with `LiveConcertsCell.self` instead of `UITableViewCell.self`. This should go in your `viewDidLoad`. Once done, post your updated `viewDidLoad ` so people don't suggest same things back again.

Comment: I get the unresolved error, but I think I know what the error is. I have more than one tableview and I used cell as the identifier for the other tableview, and when I change the identifier to cellconcerts I get a new error. http://puu.sh/kAcRJ/fed56a68dd.png. I will update my code.

Comment: I see. Sit for while, take a deep breath, have a glass of water and then take a closer look. Post your updated question if you are not able to solve it. Would be glad to take a look. All the best, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your tableview with custom cell class like

```
YOUR_TABLE_VIEW.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER)
```

Add this line in did load. If you are adding table view programmatically, add after assigning delegate and datasource.
Enjoy !!!